# how to create a for loop for this case in python?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

maybe the title seems strange, but i'm bloqued for certain times searching how to create a for loop of this case:

I have a list of lists having this format :

```
 data=[['nature', author1, author2, ...author n]
       ['sport', author1, author2, ....author n]
       ....
      ]
```

I have tried this code :

```
        authors=[author1, author2, ...author n]
         for i in range(len(authors)):

        data = [['nature', function(names[i], 'nature')],
                ['sport', function(names[i], 'sport')
             ..]
```

but unfortunately I guess it returns a result in this format :

```
 data=[['nature', author1]
       ['sport', author1]
       ....
      ]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what your desire output is?

Comment: my desire output is the fisrt code  but with a for loop

Comment: give me a few minutes I will send you an example of working code.  I am not understanding where you challenge is.  Perhaps my code will clear it up.  What Python version are you on?  I am on 3.5 just want to be sure my code works on your end.

Comment: I'm working with python2.7

Answer (score 0):

```
ary_grp_Example = [["AA1", "BB1"], ["CC2", "DD2"],["EE3","FF3"]] ### Dimension as a three column matrix array (list)
ary_grp_Example.pop(0)  ## Kill the first record leaving two

#Loop through by row (x)
for int_CurCount in range(0,len(ary_grp_Example)): 
      print ("Row: " + str(int_CurCount) 
             + " was #" 
             + str(ary_grp_Example[int_CurCount][0]) 
             + "#" + str(ary_grp_Example[int_CurCount][1]) 
             +"#")

#Loop through by Cell (x,y) 
for int_RowCount in range(0,len(ary_grp_Example)): 
   for int_ColCount in range(0,len(ary_grp_Example[int_RowCount]) ):
      print ("Cell Data for location =(" 
             + str(int_RowCount) + "," 
             + str(int_ColCount) +  ") was #" 
             + ary_grp_Example[int_RowCount][int_ColCount] 
             + "#")
```

You can get to the data if you use two numbers data[1][1] or data[1][2].  Sometimes referred to as a matrix array or matrix list.  Pythons name for it appears to be a "list" but it is a multi dimensional list aka matrix array/list.

Sport Author 2 for example would be data[1][2] as these are zero based counting.

To loop through all the data you have to loop by row and by column like you would a database result set.

Comment: when i tried to declare data as a matrix it showes me data underlined by red.. `data[i][j]= .. `

Comment: Try just running my code, insure it works for your python version.  Then change my data to your data.  See if it still works.  Let me know if that was what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want something along these lines?

```
>>> data=[['nature', 'author1', 'author2', 'author3'],['sport', 'author1', 'author2', 'author3'],['Horses', 'author1', 'author2']]
>>> for i in range(len(data)):
        for x in range(1, len(data[i])):
            print data[i][0], data[i][x] 
nature author1
nature author2
nature author3
sport author1
sport author2
sport author3
Horses author1
Horses author2
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a dictionary, and then iterate over the key pairs

```
data = [['foo', 1, 2, 3], ['bar', 2,3,4]]
dat = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in data }        
for k, v in dat.items():
    print("{0}: {1}".format(k, v))


Output
bar: [2, 3, 4]
foo: [1, 2, 3]
```

except.... *dont do this*.

I'm merely showing this to show that your data should be in a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: I generally always use the matrix array/multi dimensional list.  What is better about the "Dictionary" you are suggesting?

Comment: @mthead - I'm not even sure what the question is anymore.  I'll probably delete my answer some time soon., but if the first item in the inner arrays is always the key then you should use a data structure designed for key values.